# For graphing a time series R, how do I set a variable minimum and maximum y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, yaxis, timeserieschart

I have a large dataset of water quality data over time. I need to create somewhat standard graphs so that most sites have the same y axis scale so that viewers on our website can view graphs with a standard y axis. This makes it easier for the viewers to visually compare two or more sites with relative ease. Some sites have data outside of this standard y axis scale and we don't want to exclude those data. We want to set the minimum and maximum y axis as a standard limit and then expand when the data is larger than the base limits.

I have the following data. I tried finding a base dataset, but none seemed to fit what I was looking for. Please point me in the right direction if a base dataset exists that's similar to mine as it will be helpful for posting further questions if I have any. Apologies for the length of data; I wanted enough data points to mimic the real time series data (30 years of water quality data).

```
y <- c(SITE_ID=1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, YEAR=2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, PARAMETER="A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", VALUE=-11, -20, -50, 97.29, 11.6525, 86.3925, 12.165, 87.465, 12.7975, 91.3125, 13.1025, 98.8275, 12.97, 91.735, 10.5075, 80.3725, 16.1475, 95.395, 0.0475, 0, 0.25, 0.12, 0.3175, 0.0775, 1.2875, 0.0825, 0.9475, 0.2975, 0.26, 0.1, 1.315, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.865, 0, 109.7175, 44.1675, 107.02, 42.7725, 105.065, 43.825, 103.6375, 44.0525, 102.0975, 42.9, 100.045, 43.84, 97.2725, 43.45, 102.56, 47.1875, 94.27, 42.9325, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 10, 8, 7, 77, 68, 54, 42, 38, 22, 29, 25, 18)
```

I create the data frame from that list and reclassify the characters as numeric for YEAR and VALUE:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(y, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c("SITE_ID", "YEAR", "PARAMETER", "VALUE"))))
df$VALUE <- as.numeric(as.character(df$VALUE))
df$YEAR <- as.numeric(as.character(df$YEAR))
```

I then create a loop to create a graph for each SITE_ID in the data. I group and color by PARAMETER which are the three water quality parameters in this dataset.

```
for (site_id in unique(df$SITE_ID))
   { 
     p <- filter(df, SITE_ID == site_id) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = VALUE, group = PARAMETER, color = PARAMETER)) +
       geom_line() +
       theme_classic() +
       scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-55, 150)) + 
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2011,2013,2015,2017,2019))
}
print(p)
```

Right now I manually set the y axis limits to -55 and 150 to include all the data. When I limit it to 0 and 80, some of the data is not graphed (excluded) in the code below.

```
for (site_id in unique(df$SITE_ID))
   { 
     p <- filter(df, SITE_ID == site_id) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = VALUE, group = PARAMETER, color = PARAMETER)) +
       geom_line() +
       theme_classic() +
       scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 80)) + 
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2011,2013,2015,2017,2019))
}
print(p)
```

Is there a way to use the standard base of 0 and 80 for the y-axis, but expand the limits when the data goes beyond the limits?

I have tried the following to replace the scale_y_continuous line above, but that seems to set the max based on the max VALUE(s) for the entire dataset. We want just the max VALUE(s) for the specific SITE_ID.

```
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(df$VALUE), max(df$VALUE))) +
```

I would imagine I would limit the min and max values to specify the df$VALUE portion to just that specific SITE_ID for that loop, but not sure how to do that. Here's what it might look like just typing out what I would like it to do. I also want to incorporate an if/then statement to only run this when any value for that site is greater than 80 or less than 0.

```
(
IF min(df$VALUE) > 0 AND max(df$VALUE) <80 
    THEN scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,80)

ELSE (or IF min(df$VALUE) < 0 OR max(df$VALUE) > 80) 
    THEN scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(df$VALUE of the current SITE_ID we are graphing), max(df$VALUE of the current SITE_ID we are graphing)))
) +
```

So with this background information and steps completed so far, how do I set the minimum and maximum y axis if the values are more or less than 0 or 80, but keep the 0 and 80 limits if all data values fall within that range?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function for this...

```
plot_func <-  function(dataset,site){

 plot_df = filter(dataset, SITE_ID == site)
 min_value = ifelse(min(plot_df$VALUE)>0,0,min(plot_df$VALUE))
 max_value = ifelse(max(plot_df$VALUE)<80,80,max(plot_df$VALUE))

 p <- plot_df %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = VALUE, group = PARAMETER, color = PARAMETER)) +
   geom_line() +
   theme_classic() +
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min_value, max_value)) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2011,2013,2015,2017,2019))

  return(p)

}

for (site_id in unique(df$SITE_ID)){
   plot_out <- plot_func(df,site_id)
   print(plot_out)
 }
```

Comment: I was able to run this and it worked, but I'm not sure it's exactly what I need. I think I still need a base range (0 to 80) for when data values are within the 0 to 80 range. Let me add a third site with example data and see what happens. I'll make an edit and incorporate the third site data into my example.

Comment: @ScottR: I added an ifelse statement within the function. Try this?